# How to encode selected frames in new video with fixed framerate?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I want to make a quick encoding of a VOB file to try the effect of applied video filters, so I am encoding only the key frames to a mjpeg video.
I am using

```
ffmpeg -i input.vob -vf ...,select=key -vcodec mjpeg -an -sn test.mov
```

where ... are the filters I am trying.
This works fine, but ffmpeg duplicates thousands of times the selected keyframes to keep the input framerate and their timestamps.

Is there a way to ignore the selected frames timestamps and just create a video from them, preferably with a very slow timerate like 1 or 2 fps?

I've read the documentation, but could not figure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

After the select filter, you would insert `setpts=N/2/TB,fps=2` for a 2 fps output.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the solution. Actually, I found that the filter should be `setpts=N/(2*TB)` for a 2 fps output, which is exactly what I wanted. With `N*2/TB` each frame is still duplicated 3 times, so that each frame lasts 2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, typo corrected.